# How to add "Deleted Items" to sidebar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

how do I add the "Deleted Items" tab to the sidebar? [image]

I tried "Favorites" but that didn't work.

Comment: Deleted Items is a specific Outlook Folder and I do not think you can relocate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested in my Outlook and when I add Deleted folder to Favorites, it will be shown in the sidebar

[image: it will be shown in the sidebar].

According to my research, your "Favorites" didn't work may due to your display resolution. To check this, you can try remove some folders in "Favorites" and leave "Deleted folder" to stay then test.

Comment: Yep, I had to drag the bottom (navigation options) down.